# When enabling a button, disabling the other

Tags: python, tkinter

### Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

def all_state():
   button_list = [button1, button2, button3]
   for i in button_list:
     if i['state'] == 'disabled':
       i['state'] = 'active'

button1 = tk.Button(win, text = 'Click me', state = 'disabled', command = all_state)
button1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

button2 = tk.Button(win, text = 'Now me', state = 'active', command = all_state)
button2.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

button3 = tk.Button(win, text = 'Now', state = 'active', command = all_state)
button3.grid(column = 2, row = 0)

win.mainloop()
```

### Output:

[image: output1]

When I click any other button, I get:

[image: output2]

All buttons get enabled.

### Question:

After I've clicked one of the buttons **which aren't disabled**, I want this one to get **disabled**. Let's say I clicked button `button2`. Thus, `button2` will get disabled as shown:

[image: desired_output]

The reason why I haven't found a solution is because the button that will be **selected** is **arbitrary**, so I can't think of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass index when you call the `all_state()` also place `button_list = [button1, button2, button3]` outside the function.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

def all_state(index):

    for btn in button_list:
        btn['state'] = 'active'

    button_list[index]['state'] = 'disabled'
    
button1 = tk.Button(win, text = 'Click me', state = 'disabled', command = lambda :all_state(0))
button1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

button2 = tk.Button(win, text = 'Now me', state = 'active', command = lambda :all_state(1))
button2.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

button3 = tk.Button(win, text = 'Now', state = 'active', command = lambda :all_state(2))
button3.grid(column = 2, row = 0)

button_list = [button1, button2, button3]

win.mainloop()
```

Alternatively use `event.widget` to get the current button:

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

def all_state(event):
    btn = event.widget
    for button in win.winfo_children():
        if isinstance(button, tk.Button):
            button['state'] = 'active'

    btn['state'] = 'disabled'
    
button1 = tk.Button(win, text = 'Click me', state = 'disabled')
button1.bind('<1>', all_state)
button1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

button2 = tk.Button(win, text = 'Now me', state = 'active')
button2.bind('<1>', all_state)
button2.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

button3 = tk.Button(win, text = 'Now', state = 'active')
button3.bind('<1>', all_state)
button3.grid(column = 2, row = 0)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I have some doubts: Why do I get NameError for `button_list` if I do not include `lambda` in command options. Am I calling the subprogram?

Comment: @Nameless because when you do this `command = all_state(0)` the function is called asap even before the `button_list` is declared.

Comment: I think this answer woukd be improved if we change `btn['state'] = 'active'` to `btn['state'] = 'normal'`

Comment: @Nameless yes you could do so. I put active as it is what you have used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't super clear so I wasn't sure how you want the state of other buttons to be when a particular button was clicked. Although, here's a way you can obtain this by making the remaining buttons active:

```
def switch_state(button_name):
 bt_dict[button_name]['state'] = 'disabled'
 keys = list(bt_dict.keys())
 keys.remove(button_name)
 for i in keys:
     bt_dict[i]['state'] = 'active'
   

button1 = tk.Button(win, text = 'Click me', state = 'active', command = lambda: switch_state('button1'))

bt_dict = {'button1':button1,"button2":button2,"button3":button3}
```

and then go onto add a similar command for other buttons. If you do not want to enable the other buttons, you can remove the chunk:

```
keys = list(bt_dict.keys())
keys.remove(button_name)
 for i in keys:
     bt_dict[i]['state'] = 'active'
     print(i)
```

from your code and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I'll try it out.

Comment: In any case, the above solution should do what you are trying to obtain.